# Layer Navigation on custom collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation

We have created custom extension for clearance sale products. Collection based on the Product attribute which we have created for clearance sale.We have Block file which contains the Collection.We have follow the Webkul blog for the Navigation but we can not get success. Can anyone help us. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my extension I have filters on custom controller which loads custom collection

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Special

Comment: I have followed your extension too. But I am using Block to get collection and all the article is for Model and Controller.